# How to ignore Link component in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

```
<div key={item.productId} className="cart-item flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center border-2 border-gray-400 border-opacity-10 my-3 p-3">
                                    **<Link to={`products/${item.productId}`}>
                                        <img src={item.image} alt="" className="w-1/5 p-2" />
                                    </Link>
                                    <Link to={`products/${item.productId}`}>
                                        <div className="w-3/5 text-center p-6">{item.name}</div>
                                    </Link>**
                                    <div className="px-4">${item.price.toFixed()}</div>
                                    <div className="px-4 qty-select">
                                        <label htmlFor="qty">Qty</label>
                                        <select name="qty" >
                                            <option value={item.qty} defaultValue>{item.qty}</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <button onClick={() => {deleteCartHandler(item.productId)}} className="p-2"><i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                </div>
```

For some reason, tailwind is applying flex to my Link Components in React. So instead of being 5 items/columns (image/name/price/qty/deletebutton), it is treating the Link component as another flex item.

How can I remove or have tailwind ignore Link components or any other component? Because Link or provider tags, etc. are not HTML elements but tailwind is treating it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that I have to move the css Classnames from the image to the Link component..

Not sure if this is best practice but it did fix the problem visually

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).